# Rails Routing pass parameter with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys I'm very new to Rails and I am having trouble passing a route using ajax. I have read a few other SO posts about this issue, but I don't think I understand them correctly. How can I get ajax to use a route format Rails will recognize like: localhost:3000/welcome/show/hi-me? Or should I be changing my rails code to match the ajax?

ajax call (in index.html.erb)

```
//if url =
// /welcome/show   result: no ajax result
// welcome/show   result: GET http://localhost:3000/welcome/welcome/show?id=hi-me 404 (Not Found) 
// /show          result: GET http://localhost:3000/show?id=hi-me 404 (Not Found) 
// show           result: no ajax result

$.ajax({
    url: '/show',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {id: 'hi-me'},
    success: function(data) {console.log('success: '+data);},
    error: function(data) {console.log('error: '+data);}
 });
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/show/:id' => 'welcome#show'
get 'welcome/index'
get 'welcome/show'
```

welcome_controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #render plain: "value: |#{params[:id]}|"
    #redirect_to :controller=>'welcome', :action => 'show', :message => params[:id]
  end

  def show
    render plain: "value: #{params[:id]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: The correct value should be the `/welcome/show`. you said it returns no result, but i guess that could be another issue that needs to be solved

Comment: also you're passing `id` as a param, if you're going to do that i think you need to fix your route to `'welcome/show'` instead of `'welcome/show/:id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `/welcome/show/hi-me` then:

- Your route is correct `get 'welcome/show/:id' => 'welcome#show'`
- But your ajax isn't, you'll need to change the url to `/welcome/show/hi-me` with no `id` in the params

But if you want to use `/welcome/show?id=hi-me` then:

- Your route should be `get 'welcome/show' => 'welcome#show'`
- Your ajax would be `url: '/welcome/show'` and `params: {id: 'hi-me}`

Not sure if a redirect response for ajax calls could redirect the initiating page or not, but you could return a javascript redirect

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

then create a template called `index.js.erb`

```
window.location = '<%= whatever_path %>'
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but the first one doesnt redirect after the changes (no error in console) and the second (which I would prefer) shows success: value: in console and nothing else. Any other ideas?

Comment: ok so the 2nd method is working, but nothing is being returned? check your action in the controller, what does it return

Comment: derp, I made a syntax mistake. It now returns hi-me in console, but it doesnt redirect to the show page

Comment: you already are on the show page.. or is the ajax run from the index action?

Comment: the ajax is run from the index view page (editing my post to make that clear)

Comment: I don't know if an ajax redirect resposne is allowed to redirect the parent page or not, but you could return a script that does the redirect, ill edit my answer to show u how