# Ruby on Rails correct way to pass large amounts of data from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am very new to rails but I am trying to pass a large amount of data that is on a view to a controller so I can save it in a model. Right now I am trying to pass one parameter as a test case using AJAX shown here: [Rails Routing pass parameter with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701375/rails-routing-pass-parameter-with-ajax-beginner) but I was wondering if there is a simpler/more ruby way to do this. I looked at using a form but that didnt seem to be what I needed.

I am trying to send data pulled from other services using javascript. something like the pattern below is what I have in javascript. I am trying to save it to a rails database.

```
id: 1, name: bob, param1: xyz, .....
.....
id: 2999, name: sue, param1: abc, .....
```

I discovered one way to pass params, as a link, but it seems like a really bad solution. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: what kind of data you want to send? If you want to send it from view then i guess you want user to enter that data then this is what forms are for. If you don't want users to input the data then a view is not the place for it

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned is about showing a resource.
Since your question is a bit diffuse in what you want to achieve, I highly recommend reading about the REST pattern: [REST in piece! ...a Ruby on Rails perspective](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/03/rest-in-piece-ruby-on-rails-controller.html)
If you want to create or update a resource (model object), forms are definitely the current way to go.